# redirect to another html in angular

Tags: angular

Can someone help me please, exactly where is the comment I want to be redirected to another page being false

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!loginService.verificarToken(); else postLogin">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"><!--mr-auto-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/HOME" routerLinkActive="active">HELLO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>
     <ng-template #postLogin>
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"><!--mr-auto-->
        <!--
          in case it is false I want you to redirect me to another html page
          ????
        -->
      </ul>
     </ng-template>
```

Comment: You can use AuthGuard and it will handle what you want this the ideal solution. I have a solution but i consider it very bad which is adding a component inside <ng-template #postLogin> and it will be responsible for redirecting as i mentioned before it is a very bad solution

Comment: What I try to do exactly is verify, if there is a token, take me to the home page, if there is no redirect to the login

Comment: Exactly this is what AuthGuard will do for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you have the HTML and you also have the component, where most of the logic happens. You can insert logic in the HTML to render stuff, or show stuff based on a certain condition or pretty much any DOM manipulation but what you are trying to do doesn't relate to the DOM at all.

You want to run you code in the component and not the HTML, remember the the logic in the HTML is used mostly to render certain things and manipulate the DOM.

**So here's how to do this:**

When do you want your function to run? If you want it to run when the page renders for example, use the NgOnInit lifecycle hook. Here's a simple implementation of it.

```js
export class App implements OnInit {
       constructor(private router: Router) { }
      ngOnInit() {
           if (!loginService.verificarToken()) {
              this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

      }
    }
```

Few things to note:

1. I'd recommend to run this type of logic in your code but instead to use a Route Guard, that will run before each page. Checkout:
   https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access
2. I don't recommend putting functions inside your HTML, it's not good for performance. Instead use variables in your HTML and run the function in the component.

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router)

```
postloginRedirect(){
  router.navigate(['/routeforPostlogin']);
}
```

And in your HTML
<

```
ng-template #postLogin>
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"><!--mr-auto-->
    <span [hidden]="postloginRedirect()"></span>        
    <!--
              in case it is false I want you to redirect me to another html page
              ????
            -->
          </ul>
         </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app-routing.module.ts add your route:

```
    import { pageNameComponent} from './pageNameComponent.component';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/AppComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'pageName', component: pageNameComponent },
    
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
      exports: [ RouterModule ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And in your html:

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"><!--mr-auto-->
       <a routerLink="/pageName" class="nav-link" href="#">pageName</a>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go the Angular way which is using Router -> CanActivate

Angular guard AuthGuard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import {
  CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router'

import { LoginService } from './login.service' // <-- your service

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: LoginService
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      const isLoggedIn = this.loginService.verificarToken() // <-- verificarToken boolean

      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        this.router.navigate(['login') // <-- redirect to login
      }

      return isLoggedIn
  }
}
```

And then in your routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: UsersComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], // <-- your guard redirect
  },
  // ...
]
```